# Modifying Date.prototype and binding this

Tags: binding, prototype

Simple task and many questions.

I needed a simple way to display the week day.
For this the easiest way was modifying the Date.prototype as follow:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekDay = function () {
  const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return weekday[this.getDay()];
}
```

I know, that we generally should avoid modifying prototype. But in this case I don't think that it causes any problems. Am I right? Can I do so? Or is it considering bad coding?

The second question is regarding the binding the this in arrow functions.
If I modify the above function to an arrow function like this:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekDay = () => {
  const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return weekday[this.getDay()];
}
```

The function doesn't work any more, because of the this keyword. I know that I have to bind this but I don't know how to do so. How should I bind this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

From the ECMAScript 2015 Spec:

> Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an
>   ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing
>   environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an
>   immediately enclosing function.

So basically you cannot rebind it

Comment: What about the first question?

Comment: I have no idea, if you want to get away without doing it ,maybe make a function wich takes a Date as an argument?